# Android notification panel, rooting, android lollipop

Tags: rooting

How can I replace my stock notification panel with that of android lollipop? I have root access. I am using Sony's xperia.

Comment: Which android version are you on,now? You can install Cyanogenmod12 from http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Devices

Comment: Did you try searching for an Xposed module? See HTG guide about Xposed Framework: http://www.howtogeek.com/195476/7-things-you-can-do-with-the-xposed-framework-on-a-rooted-android-phone-or-tablet/

Answer (score 1):

1. Install [Xposed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer).
2. Install [Busybox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en).
3. Now install [MonsterUI](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.kuaq.monsterui).

MonsterUI does the magic here. Xposed framework and Busybox are supporting apps and are mandatory.This module almost changes everything in Jellybean and Kitkat.

**Edit:** [About MonsterUI](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.kuaq.monsterui):

> This module allows you to theme your phone to look like Material Design devices (Lollipop). You can use theme accent color, use ripple effect, animated checkboxes and many many more!

YouTube Links:

- [MonsterUI 4.5 Lollipop recent panel & Animations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TkKsOpADEfQ)
- [MonsterUI 3.0 - presentation -Theme your device to Material Design!](https://youtu.be/8BYx4S7LyD4)

Comment: Could you please share screenshots showing the difference before and after the usage of this module?

Comment: Please go through xda-developers.com. I can't do it now because I have unrooted my phone recently. But I can assure that the module will work.

Comment: @Firelord- Nicely edited